# Cast binary column to string in Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse, sql-data-warehouse

I currently have functions in Postgres and Redshift that take a randomly generated string, hash it, then uses part of the hash to generate a random number between 0-99. I am trying to replicate this functionality in  Azure SQL Data Warehouse such that I get the same value in SQL DW as I do in Postgres and Redshift.

The issue I'm running into is when I cast the result to a VARCHAR or use a string function the result is a much different string. I'd like to get the result of the md5 function as an identical `VARCHAR`.

To illustrate, here is a query in Azure SQL DW:

```
SELECT
  'abc123' as random_string,
  HASHBYTES('md5', 'abc123') as md5,
  CAST(HASHBYTES('md5', 'abc123') AS VARCHAR) as md5_varchar,
  RIGHT(HASHBYTES('md5', 'abc123'), 5) as md5_right
;
```

This yields

```
random_string,md5,md5_varchar
abc123,0xE99A18C428CB38D5F260853678922E03,éšÄ(Ë8Õò`…6x’.,6x’.
```

As you can see, the resulting varchar is much different from the output of the md5 function. Is there a way to convert the result of md5 into an identical string?

In Postgres and Redshift the result of the `md5` function is a VARCHAR so it is simple to do transformations on it.

Here are the queries in Redshift and Postgres:

```
-- Redshift
SELECT
  'abc123' as random_string,
  right(strtol(right(md5('abc123'), 3), 16), 2)::INT as tranche
;

-- Postgres
SELECT
  'abc123' as random_string,
  right(('x' || lpad(right(md5('abc123'), 3), 4, '0')) :: BIT(16) :: INT :: VARCHAR, 2) :: INT AS tranche
;
```

Both functions return the value `87`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using convert should solve that problem:

`CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),HashBytes('MD5', 'abc123'),2)`

It is because you can define parameter for style which is needed as we convert  varbinary value. It is described here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms187928(v=sql.105).aspx

Here is Remarks part from that documentation about binary conversion with convert:

> Binary Styles When expression is binary(n), varbinary(n), char(n), or
> varchar(n), style can be one of the values shown in the following
> table. Style values that are not listed in the table return an error.
>
> 0 (default)
>
> Translates ASCII characters to binary bytes or binary
> bytes to ASCII characters. Each character or byte is converted 1:1. If
> the data_type is a binary type, the characters 0x are added to the
> left of the result.
>
> 1, 2
>
> If the data_type is a binary type, the
> expression must be a character expression. The expression must be
> composed of an even number of hexadecimal digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,
> 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F, a, b, c, d, e, f). If the style is set to 1
> the characters 0x must be the first two characters in the expression.
> If the expression contains an odd number of characters or if any of
> the characters are invalid an error is raised. If the length of the
> converted expression is greater than the length of the data_type the
> result will be right truncated. Fixed length data_types that are
> larger then the converted result will have zeros added to the right of
> the result. If the data_type is a character type, the expression must
> be a binary expression. Each binary character is converted into two
> hexadecimal characters. If the length of the converted expression is
> greater than the data_type length it will be right truncated. If the
> data_type is a fix sized character type and the length of the
> converted result is less than its length of the data_type; spaces are
> added to the right of the converted expression to maintain an even
> number of hexadecimal digits. The characters 0x will be added to the
> left of the converted result for style 1.